# Proof that the inverse of a square matrix is unique

Tags: matrices

From my textbook

> ... if a 2×2 matrix $A$ is invertible then its inverse is unique.

I wonder, how can one prove this? Also can one extend this proof to larger square matrices of order $n$? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102882/prove-if-an-element-of-a-monoid-has-an-inverse-that-inverse-is-unique). Don't let the fancy word “monoid” scare you. It just means you have an associative product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ is a group and the proof of  unicity of the inverse of a matrix is the same proof in any group. Let $A$ a given invertible matrix and denote $B$ and $C$ two inverses of $A$. Then:
$$B=BI=B(AC)=(BA)C=IC=C$$

Comment: Thanks matrix multiplication is associative right?

Comment: Yes. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*:

Assume that there exists two inverses of $A$. This means $AB=BA=I=AC=CA$. Now, what happens if I multiply the equality $AB=I$ by $C$ from the left?

Comment: ABC=C right?... hmm then B(AC)=C then B=C right?

Comment: @user167391 No, you don't get $ABC$, matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: C(AB)=IC right? but then I can't get anywhere

Comment: Ah yes: $C = IC = ( BA ) C = B ( AC ) = BI = B$. Matrix multiplication is associative right?

Comment: If course, multiplication is indeed asociative. Your proof is OK now. Do you think it holds for $n=2$ or is it more general?

Comment: more general...

Comment: @user167391 So you answered the second part of your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

We are treating matrices as linear transformation and a linear transformation is a function (T: $R^n$ -> $R^m$ ).

A function (f: x -> y) is invertible if it is one-one and onto i.e. for every x there is a unique y and for every y there is an x. So a function is not invertible when multiple x's map to the same y or when some y's are not produced by any x.

On applying a similar analogy to invertibility of matrices (Ax=b where x= $A^{-1}$b) then a matrix would not be invertible when

1. There are some b's for which A$x_1$=b and A$x_2$=b. Because in this case $A^{-1}$ will not give a unique value of x. (infinite solutions)
2. There are some b's which are not produced by any x. (No solution)

So a matrix is invertible only when there is a unique x for every b. (One solution)

Comment: Hello @Arup Das, welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to typeset the math formulas in an answer. A tutorial can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).